# Java Null Dereference Garbage Collection (from Fortify scan)

Tags: java, null, dereference, garbage

My Java is kinda rusty...especially on garbage collection, so I could use a little help finding the solution to how this is improperly ending in a "null" at the end of this:

```
public void copyFileBuffered(String inPUT, String outPUT) throws
        FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try{
        if(inPUT != null)
        is = new FileInputStream(inPUT);
        if(outPUT != null)
        os = new FileOutputStream(outPUT);
        int count = 0;
        byte b[] = new byte[BLKSIZ];
        while ((count = is.read(b)) != -1) {  /** FORTIFY ERROR LINE */
            os.write(b, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    finally{
        if(is != null)
            is.close();
        if(os != null)
            os.close();
    }

}
```

from what I see it's taken care of by "os = new FileOutputStream(outPUT);" 
FORTIFY: the method copyFileBuffered() is dereferencing a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your if-statements are verbatim and explicit in stating the following:

- If `inPUT` is `null`, then `is` is `null`.
- If `outPUT` is `null`, then `os` is `null`.

Static analysis would tell your code that you *might* be dereferencing `null`, which would be a significant bug.

You don't tell us where those come from, so if you're running into an actually `NullPointerException`, be sure that neither `inPUT` nor `outPUT` are actually being passed through as `null` to this chunk of code.

Comment: Thank you, I added more of the function

Comment: What would be a good way to safeguard "os" then from being the null dereference? Above the error line if os equals null then make os ??

Comment: You could use `Objects.requireNonNull` for both parameters inside of your method (before your `if` block).  Your code would then throw an expected `NullPointerException` if either value you passed to it was `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!